# On windows 7 - Set core Affinity on boot, Or bulk affinity/tasking tool? (Like a KsysGuard for windows)

Tags: cpu, task-manager, affinity

Not even sure if its possible but: 
you know how you can set custom scheduling in Linux.
→ and sure, I can set affinity for Windows 7 Programs one @ a time.
But do you know of a tool that would allow me to multi select and masq to core?
Going one by one is just... frustrating.

Or → A way to set windows to use only assign one core on boot (But not disabling the others)?

If it helps, this is why I need this.
AMD turbo is... not too bright on windows 7, or perhaps windows 7 is not too bright (going with that)
So, I want to offload basic programs to low Cstate CPUs → Like Chrome on my second monitor.
 → Then put my game/virtual machine or whatnot on the 4 remaining locked turbo cores.